# SCALA: How to Construct a composite Type That can accept any of Int, Long or BigInt implicitly

Tags: scala, types

Suppose I want a Type T such that if I type in

### SCALA REPL :

```
  val x:T = 34
  x: BigInt = 34

  val y:T = 34L
  y: BigInt = 34

  val z:T = BigInt(34)
  z: BigInt = 34
```

This means I need to construct a Type T using Int, Long and BigInt Types which returns as BigInt in SCALA REPL.
Or Better even if I get:

```
 val x:T = 34
 x: T = 34

 val y:T = 34L
 y: T = 34

 val z:T = BigInt(34)
 z: T = 34
```

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to unify two primitive types of different sizes, and additionally one reference type? That's probably one of the most annoying problem you could attempt to solve on the JVM, and probably there is essentially no payoff, because the whole construction is gonna break down at thousand other places. Looks like an XY problem anyway.

Comment: That is what I realized finally...But I just want to be certain whether such a construction new composite type possible which can be localized to a particular function.

Comment: Composite/Union types are on the way. Check out [dotty](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/union-types.html)

Comment: Great reference James. Thank you. I am not aware of it!

Comment: @AndreyTyukin : I gave it a try in Dotty REPL and I could confirm that Union types can be specialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BigInt` is your `T` type.
Scala has built in implicit conversions for that.
e.g.

```
val x: BigInt = 34

val y: BigInt = 34L

val z: BigInt = BigInt(34)
```

will all work.

If you want a different type than BigInt you can use an implicit conversion

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

class BigIntWrapper(val value: BigInt) extends AnyVal

implicit def IntegralIsBigInt[T: Integral](num: T): BigIntWrapper = {
    val ev = implicitly[Integral[T]]
    new BigIntWrapper(BigInt(ev.toLong(num)))
}

val a: BigIntWrapper = 4
val b: BigIntWrapper = 4L
```

Comment: I want to write a Varargs function like def myFunc[T](varied: T*): T where varied may contain any of Int or Long or BigInt or their combination.

Comment: @RAGHHURAAMM I don't understand what you are trying to do. Maybe edit your question and clarify. `def fn(args: BigInt*): BigInt = args.sum` is something that will work like `fn(1, 2, 4L)`

Comment: Yes. I understand this clearly....But Using Type Parameters,...if I want a gcd function that works for this...with varied parameters of varied types with a single Type parameter T....like if I type gcd(BigInt(21),14L, 35,BigInt(28))...answer 7(BigInt)

Comment: @RAGHHURAAMM Why do you need a type parameter?

Comment: Actually this function works: But not for the combination of Types..                  def gcd[A:scala.Integral](xs: A*): A = {def gcd1[A:scala.Integral](a: A, b: A): A = {
  val value = implicitly[scala.Integral[A]]
  if (value.equiv(b, value.fromInt(0))) a else gcd1(b, value.rem(a, b))
}
xs.reduce(gcd1(_, _))

}

Comment: And I have written a function but without Type parameters works fine for all:                      implicit def gcd(varied:BigInt*):BigInt = {
                  val xs = varied.toList;
                  val result = xs match {
                        case Nil  => BigInt(0)
                        case h::Nil => h
                        case first::next::rest => {  var c = if(next==0) first else gcd(next,first%next);
                                                      if(rest.isEmpty) c else gcd((c::rest): _*)   }
                      }  
     result 
 }

Comment: My thought is can't we write a composite type and use that type and write a function purely using that single composite type?